# How do I create a UIViewController to slide up from bottom with dimmed background

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uikit

I don’t really know where to start as I’m still new to UIKit, but all I want to do is when I tap the middle tab button, which I’m handling already right now and it will slide up a view controller that sits and covers the screen and the background is dimmed so you can see what’s on the background. The height of the main contents only takes up about 40% of the screen from the bottom.

And I want to have this appear with a slide up animation. Any pointers on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: You need a presented view controller, a custom transition animation, and a UIPresentationController subclass. You might want to study my downloadable example here: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7 It's a different animation and a different size, but it dims the background and it shows the technique you'll need.

Comment: Does that help @wpa ?

Comment: @matt thanks, I had a look, bit confusing, trying to wrap my head around all these different classes to right to enable it.

Comment: Create a custom View with the height of 40% of the screen, when you tap the button, slide up the view with animation.